# How to compare a model property for No Equality with multiple fields in Model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC technology. Today i got an assignment to make a form where user can enter multiple email address on form. I need to stop user from entering duplicate email address in other text-boxes. I have created a custom validator for comparing called "NonEqualValidation" as given below

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class NonEqualValidation : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "Duplicate e-mail not allowed";
    public string OtherProperty { get; private set; }
    public string OtherPropertyName { get; private set; }

    public NonEqualValidation(string otherProperty, string otherPropertyName): base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
        OtherProperty = otherProperty;
        OtherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var otherProperty = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(OtherProperty);

            var otherPropertyValue = otherProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (value.Equals(otherPropertyValue))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;

    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        {
            ValidationType = "unlike",
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
        };

        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherproperty", OtherProperty);
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherpropertyname", OtherPropertyName);

        yield return rule;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name, OtherPropertyName);
    }
}
```

My Model structure is like below :

```
 [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid e-mail address")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND2", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND3", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND4", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND5", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    public string MAILFRIEND1 { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid e-mail address")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND1", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND3", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND4", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND5", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    public string MAILFRIEND2 { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid e-mail address")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND1", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND2", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND4", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND5", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    public string MAILFRIEND3 { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid e-mail address")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND1", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND2", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND3", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND5", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
    public string MAILFRIEND4 { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid e-mail address")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND1", "E-mail is use above")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND2", "E-mail is use above")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND3", "E-mail is use above")]
    [NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND4", "E-mail is use above")]
    public string MAILFRIEND5 { get; set; }
```

But still expected result is not coming. If i enter duplicate value as well in that it's not working. Can somebody help out on this.

I have added this jquery validation as well to make it at client side like given in below post.I am not able to paste it as giving error:

http://macaalay.com/2014/02/25/unobtrusive-client-and-server-side-not-equal-to-validation-in-mvc-using-custom-data-annotations/

Comment: Not working server side or client side (or both)?

Comment: It is client side. I am using jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js to make it work at client side using data annotations

Comment: Have you added a method to the jquery validator? (e.g. `$.validator.addMethod(...)`). [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) have a `[NotEqualTo]` attribute which does just this (tried and tested!). If you want to create you own, it might be worthwhile studying the source code.

Comment: I have created validation attribute as you can see above as i am using client side validation using data-annotations

Comment: But you have not created the associated jquery code to work with `jquery-validate-unobtrusive.js` so you wont get client side validation. [This article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) might help your understanding

Comment: I have added method for this. I have updated question and given link which i am following

Comment: Yes i have followed same that's why its working for  some cases. .Issue is that i need to compare same field with multiple one so i have to put same validator multiple time on a field. I have done that as you can see above but that is not working correctly

Comment: Hard to comment without seeing the jquery code or the details of ant errors you may be getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Remote validation.
Model

```
[Remote("doesEmailExist", "Email", HttpMethod = "Post", ErrorMessage = "Email already exist.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

In Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult doesEmailExist([Bind(Prefix = "Email.EmailName")]string EmailName)
        {
            var email = db.Emails.FirstOrDefault(a => a.EmailName == EmailName);
            return Json(email == null);
        }
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: For OP's case this wont work since it only checks existing values in the database, not the values the user is entered in other textboxes on the form (they have not been saved yet). It could possibly be adapted to pass back the values of the other tetboxes using `AdditionalFields` but it would be overkill to call the server just to check whats on the client. And of course `[Remote]` does not give server side validation

Answer (score 0):

You are close.

**Custom Attribute Implementation:**
Instead of implementing a new custom attribute from scratch, create one that derives from CompareAttribute. Then override the IsValid Method.

**Model:**
Since you have 5 email properties, I would put one CustomAttribute on each email property that would check against one other email property.

Something like this:

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid e-mail address")]
[NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND5", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
public string MAILFRIEND1 { get; set; }

[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid e-mail address")]
[NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND1", "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
public string MAILFRIEND2 { get; set; }

[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid e-mail address")]
[NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND2, "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
public string MAILFRIEND3 { get; set; }

[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid e-mail address")]
[NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND3, "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
public string MAILFRIEND4 { get; set; }

[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid e-mail address")]
[NonEqualValidation("MAILFRIEND4, "Duplicate e-mail not allowed")]
public string MAILFRIEND5 { get; set; }
```

Comment: But here we have one problem. Email 1 will only validate with Email 5 while duplicate email can be in any field like MAILFRIEND2, MAILFRIEND3, MAILFRIEND4 or MAILFRIEND5. Any suggestion over this?

Comment: Makes sense. I was only using 3 properties. In that case you can build a custom attribute. See below

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample custom attribute.

You can add properties you want to compare as a comma delimited string.

```
 public class CompareNotEqualAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{


    public List<string> CompareProperties { get; set; }
    public CompareNotEqualAttribute(string compareproperty)
    {
            CompareProperties = compareproperty.Split(',').ToList();
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        foreach(var compareProperty in CompareProperties)
        {
            var otherProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(compareProperty);
            if (otherProperty == null)
                return new ValidationResult(String.Format("Unknown property: {0}.", otherProperty));
            // get the other value
            var other = otherProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (other.Equals(value))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can Implement this:

```
 public class CompareNotEqualAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    public List<string> CompareProperties { get; set; }

    public CompareNotEqualAttribute(string compareproperty)
    {
            CompareProperties = compareproperty.Split(',').ToList();
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        foreach(var compareProperty in CompareProperties)
        {
            var otherProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(compareProperty);
            if (otherProperty == null)
                return new ValidationResult(String.Format("Unknown property: {0}.", otherProperty));
            // get the other value
            var other = otherProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (other.Equals(value))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in your Attributes, list the other email addresses, comma delimited.